# NuGet Packages for Selenium 2 WebDriver won't install in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, nuget, nuget-package

I'm trying to get Selenium 2 WebDriver up and running locally on Windows 7.  For some reason I am unable to install my NuGet packages I downloaded from here:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/2.17.0

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Visual Studio 2010 > Tools > Library Package Manager > Package Manager Console

```
PM> Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter DotNetZip

Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                                                                                                      
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                                                                                                      
DotNetZip                      1.9.1.8              DotNetZip is an easy-to-use, FAST, FREE class library and toolset for manipulating zip files or folders.                                                                       
DotNetZip.Reduced              1.9.1.8              DotNetZip is an easy-to-use, FAST, FREE class library and toolset for manipulating zip files or folders.                                                                       


PM> Install-Package DotNetZip
Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  DotNetZip
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoActiveSolution,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Do you have a solution open at the time as per the message?

Comment: no, I closed all solutions/projects .. Solution Explorer is empty and the only tab that's open is the "Start Page"

Comment: Is it not saying that you need one open?

Comment: you cannot add library to solution with nuget without solution. so try to create one.

Comment: sorry I wasted your time.  I must be tired today.  +1*2

Comment: Its no problem chances are someone else will run into this :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try having a solution open when running install as per the message.

```
Install-Package : The current environment doesn't have a solution open.
```

Comment: On mine I see a solution "open" on the right side, I am editing files and all. Yet it says the same error.

Answer (score 1):

At first, it had a corrupted NuGet install.  When I tried uninstalling NuGet, it gave me an error that said, "cannot create a file when that file already exists".  I had to close Visual Studio 2010 and go into folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation" and delete the extension explicitly from there.  Then re-install "NuGet.Tools.vsix".

Then I had to make sure I had a solution open in Visual Studio 2010.  That solved it.

Comment: The edit you left on the other answer? Don't do that. That kind of commentary doesn't belong in the answer, and editing it in is an abuse of the editing system. Just accept your own answer if it is indeed the *correct* one.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try going to...

Visual Studio 2010 > Tools > Library Package Manager > Manage Nuget Packages

instead, then search on selenium.

It worked for me. If you dont have the Manage Nuget Packages option. Try uninstalling then reinstalling the nuget package manager. I noticed I had to do this on some machines.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving your solution before installing Nuget packages

Comment: This question already has an accepted answer (green checkmark).  Thanks for the suggestion though.